# Game of cards and divisors

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, game-theory, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-game-theory

Ana thinks about some different non-zero natural numbers, and for each of them, she writes on a card every positive divisor. Then, Ana hands all the cards to Maria, who groups them based on the number written on each, defining the sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ for which $a_k$ is the number of cards with the number $k$, for any $k \geq 1$.

Finally, for each non-zero term $a_k$ of this sequence, Maria writes on the board the value of the number $k^{a_k}$. Show that, by looking at the board, we can determine at least one of the numbers Ana had in mind.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I need help finding a solution. I have only observed that the product of Ana’s divisors is the same as the product of the numbers written on the board.
I took the case with primes:
Let's consider a prime number, say p, in Ana's set. The only divisors of a prime number are 1 and itself. Therefore, in Maria's sequence, there will be a term $a_p$ indicating the count of cards with the number p.

Now, Maria writes on the board the value $p^{a_p}$. Since p is a prime number, the only way to represent it in this form is if $a_p$ is 1. Thus, we can deduce the presence of the prime number p in Ana's set. But I don’t know how to generalize it when we have composite numbers.

Source: rmg 2023

Comment: Well, why not do it for two numbers?  See how that works out...then either try three numbers or use what you learned to try to settle the whole thing.

Comment: Just to illustrate the rules:  if Ana is thinking of $2,4$ then she writes $1,2$ on one card and $1,2,4$ on another.  This makes $\{a_n\}=\{2,2,0,1,0,0,\cdots\}$ right?  So Maria would then write $(1,4,4)$  ($=(1^2, 2^2,4^1)$), right?  But the product of those number is $16$, which is not the product of $2,4$. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @lulu I referenced the same issue in my comment. $\quad$ (like you mentioned) Note that Maria will write $\{ 1, 4, 4 \}$, and not $ \{ 1^2, 2^2, 4^1 \}$. In the latter case, if there is a $ k^1$, we can guess $k$ directly.

Comment: @CalvinLin agreed.   I only wrote the exponent version to indicate where the $1,4,4$ came from.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I think “the product of Ana’s numbers” is meant to refer not to the product of what was introduced as numbers but to the product of what was introduced as divisors.

Comment: @jorki you are correct. I should’ve been more clear in the text. I’ll modify it now

Comment: Does Maria write the numbers **in order** starting from $k=1$ and continuing with increasing values of $k$ for which $a_k$ are non-zero?

Comment: It can be noted that the largest number Anna thought of will always be written on the board, and if the values are written in order with increasing $k$ then it will be the last.

Comment: @Sahaj If that's the case, once the largest number is known, its effects can be removed from the list, and then we have the second largest, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the prime factorization of all the positive integers written on the board.

All integers on the board are of form $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots$ Write each integer on the board in the form $(p_1^{b_1}\cdot p_2^{b_2}\dots)^n$ where $\gcd(b_1,b_2,\dots)=1$ and label each $(p_1^{b_1}\cdot p_2^{b_2}\dots)^n = t_k^n$. Consider the set $S_{t_k}$ which consists of all powers of $t_k$ that are on the board.

**Claim**: $|S_{t_k}|$ gives the highest power of $t_k$ that divides some of the terms of Anna's sequence.

If $t_k^n$ is the highest power of $t_k$ dividing any term, then all powers of $t_k$ till $n$ act as divisors. Then our claim follows because while writing the terms down Maria has to write the first $n$ powers of $t_k$, each raised to some number depending on how many times they are repeated on the cards.

Suppose the largest number in Anna's sequence is $k$. It follows that out of all divisors of all numbers, $k$ will be their maximum (since the divisors of $n$ are $\le n$). Hence in order to find it we can just find the maximum value of $t_k^{|S_{t_k}|}$.

**Claim**: If the board has some integers of the form $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots$ where we already have that $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots)=1$ then the largest multiple of $n$ is also on Anna's list.

Since this number can't be written in the form $a^b$ for integral $a>1$ and $b>2$, this integer is a divisor of exactly one integer $k$ (not necessarily the greatest) in Anna's list. That means all multiples of $n$ on the board are some divisors of $k$, and the largest such multiple of $n$ on the board is $k$ itself.

Example: suppose you see $$1, 49, 49, 32, 64, 8, 14, 28, 56, 27, 216, 81, 144, 324, 36, 43, 86$$ on the board. Since $14=7\cdot 2$, the greatest multiple of $14$, which is $56$ on the board, will be on Anna's mind. Considering all $t_k^{|S_{t_k}|}$, we get that out of $7^2$, $2^3$, $14$, $28$, $56$, $3^2$, $6^2$, $18$, $12$, $43$ and $86$, it is easy to tell $86$ is the maximum value that divides some of the terms of Anna's sequence, and is in turn the maximum value thereof.

Another example is that of $$1, 8, 27, 16, 216, 81, 144, 324, 36$$ wherefrom we get the maximum powers of all divisors $2^2$, $3^2$, $6^2$, $18$ and $12$, and the maximum divisor is $36$. Indeed the sequence was generated by using $12,18,36$.

Comment: I don't really understand in the first example how can 86 divide all of Anna's terms and in the second example how did you get 36 in the sequence if 6 is a divisor of all three numbers

Comment: Could you please be more specific cause I don’t really understand the examples

Comment: Are there in the second example 3 powers of 6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151163/discussion-between-math-enthusiast9-and-sahaj).